# Calculate a transform matrix between two component spaces in UE5.1

Tags: c++, unreal-engine5

I want to obtain a 4x4 transform matrix from the local space of an StaticMesh Actor to the local space of an (unrelated) StaticMeshComponent. This matrix will then be used in a custom HLSL compute shader to transform a position from the actor's space to the components.

I obtain the actor transform via `actor->GetActorTransform()` and the component transform via `component->GetComponentTransform()`

I know I can get the matrix for a `FTransform` through `GetMatrixWithScale()` and `GetMatrixWithNoScale()` functions.
I am also aware of the `GetRelativeTransform()` and `GetRelativeTransformReversed()` functions

However, as far as I can tell none of these do what I want. In particular they break when objects have both non-uniform scaling and a rotation.

I have calculated what I believe is the correct matrix as following:

```cpp
FMatrix44d makeWorldToLocalTransformMatrix(const FTransform& transform) {
    auto L2WTranslation = makeTranslationMatrix(transform.GetTranslation()).InverseFast(); // Inverted
    auto L2WRotation = transform.GetRotation().ToMatrix(); // NOT Inverted
    auto L2WScale = makeScaleMatrix(transform.GetScale3D()).InverseFast(); // Inverted
    return L2WScale * L2WRotation * L2WTranslation;
}


FMatrix44d makeLocalToWorldTransformMatrix(const FTransform& transform) {

    auto L2WTranslation = makeTranslationMatrix(transform.GetTranslation()); // NOT Inverted
    auto L2WRotation = transform.GetRotation().ToMatrix().InverseFast(); // Inverted
    auto L2WScale = makeScaleMatrix(transform.GetScale3D()); // NOT Inverted
    return L2WTranslation * L2WRotation * L2WScale;
}

FMatrix44d getLocalToLocalTransformMatrix(const FTransform& actor, const FTransform& component) {
    auto actorTransformMatrix = makeLocalToWorldTransformMatrix(actor);
    auto componentTransformMatrix = makeWorldToLocalTransformMatrix(component);
    return componentTransformMatrix * actorTransformMatrix;
}
```

But I would rather use a built-in function as this solution is not particularly efficient.

In the shader the matrix is used like:

```
float4x4 TransformMatrix = ...;
float4 PositionToTransform = float4(..., 1)
float4 result = mul(TransformMatrix, PositionToTransform);
```

It seems to me that either:

1. There must be a built-in function that can achieve this
2. There is some other approach that I am unaware of for achieving the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that the result of `GetMatrixWithScale()` was the transpose of what I was expecting

This means instead of:

```cpp
FMatrix44d getLocalToLocalTransformMatrix(const FTransform& actor, const FTransform& component) {
    auto actorTransformMatrix = actor.GetMatrixWithScale();
    auto componentTransformMatrix = component.GetMatrixWithScale().InverseFast();
    return componentTransformMatrix * actorTransformMatrix; // WRONG!
}
```

The correct function was

```cpp
FMatrix44d getLocalToLocalTransformMatrix(const FTransform& actor, const FTransform& component) {
    auto actorTransformMatrix = actor.GetMatrixWithScale();
    auto componentTransformMatrix = component.GetMatrixWithScale().InverseFast();
    return (actorTransformMatrix * componentTransformMatrix).GetTransposed(); // Fixed
}
```

I'm unsure as to why this is the chosen behaviour, but looking elsewhere it seems that several places use `Vector * Matrix` as the preferred order for matrix multiplication.